# Periodically run WCF method automatically

Tags: wcf

I have `WCF` hosted in `IIS`. There is a service method which gets the latest Db table record and do some work.
I want my web service to periodically cheks the database table and if there is new record deposited in the table then do the work.

I know how to handle this If my `WCF` hosted as `windows service`. But have no idea to do with IIS hosted WPF.

Please advice me.

Comment: Run a separate thread on a timer - every x period of time, poll the database.

Comment: @Tim- Where should I place the code? Can you please provide me good URL.

Comment: @Tim is this a good solution. When the application gets idle in IIS it could be that the worker process gets shutdown. So that your timer won´t execute. I would recommend to use the TaskScheduler of the Windows OS or a Quartz-Service to run periodical task that are not started by a user.

Comment: @Jehof - Good point.  I skimmed the question and saw WPF (typo of WCF), so I was thinking it was being hosted in WPF.  Under IIS though your point is valid.  Windows Service, Task Scheduler or similar options (I'm not familiar with Quartz) would be the place for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

if u need your wcf service to be invoked at some defined intervals, you can use **Quartz Scheduler**, where we  can specify a particular task to be executed at defined intervals

pls check this link

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/

It will basically be a Windows Service, with your WCF service reference added to it.

you can just use the Quartz API.